# .OrderBy multiple columns with .GroupBy

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am working on an application that has a dropdown for facilities which should be grouped by state, ordered by the name of the facility alphabetically within the state grouping, and then the state group needs to be ordered alphabetically, as well.  The initial list of data is built like this:

```
_pageFacilityData.Add(new FacilityDTO {
    ClientID = (long) fds.ClientId,
    FacilityID = fds.FacilityId,
    Name = fds.Name,
    State = fds.State
});
```

And the current LINQ statement (that does *not* order the state groupings alphabetically looks like this:

```
var groupedByState = _pageFacilityData.GroupBy(x => x.State).OrderBy(y => y.Key).ToList();
```

I've looked for a solution to this, but haven't been able to find an answer that does what I need.  Also, just to clarify, this code was written by someone else.  I'm still not 100% sure where the y.Key value comes from, or how it is being set.

For further clarification, the data is being used in a .cshtml view like this:

```
@foreach (var state in ViewBag.FacilityDTOs) {
    <optgroup id=@state label=@state>
        @foreach (var facility in state) {
            <option id="c @facility.FacilityID" value="@facility.FacilityID">@facility.Name</option>
        }
    </optgroup>
}
```

Comment: What is the `Type` of `y.Key`?

Comment: The `.Key` property is not actually a property used by my models or code.  As far as I can tell, it's part of the IGrouping created by the query.

Comment: `I'm still not 100% sure where the y.Key value comes from, or how it is being set.` Have a look at the documentation to see what `GroupBy` returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can order the within list when grouping:

```
var groupedByState = _pageFacilityData
    .GroupBy(
        x => x.State,
        x=>x,
        (k,v)=>new KeyValuePair<string,List<FacilityDTO>>(k, v.OrderBy(y=>y.Name).ToList()))
    .OrderBy(y => y.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Edit: Try this in the cshtml:

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string,List<FacilityDTO>> state in ViewBag.FacilityDTOs) {
    <optgroup id=@state.Key label=@state.Key>
        @foreach (var facility in state.Value) {
            <option id="c @facility.FacilityID" value="@facility.FacilityID">@facility.Name</option>
        }
    </optgroup>
}
```

Comment: I get the same error with this solution when the View using the data is loaded as I do with the other solution: `RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'`

Comment: @travisdmcdaniel well, you added new info to the question. Who is `ViewBag.FacilityDTOs` that's not in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't expecting the code on the .cshtml page to start causing problems. `ViewBag.FacilityDTOs` is being set equal to the `groupedByState` variable in the controller.

Comment: @travisdmcdaniel Try my edit and see if that works.

Comment: Same error.  The specific line that seems to be causing the error (where Key is causing the problem) is `<optgroup id=@state.Key label=@state.Key>`

Comment: @travisdmcdaniel try the new edited code (c# and cshtml)

Comment: The page loads correctly now, but the dropdown still is not sorted correctly.  The states actually seem to be listed in the same order as they were before any of these changes.  The facilities are in alphabetical order, though.

Comment: What's state type?

Comment: @travisdmcdaniel I suspect your State is an enum, not an string, can you confirm its type?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you are looking for:

```
var groupedByState = _pageFacilityData.OrderBy(x => x.State).GroupBy(x => x.State).Select(g => g.OrderBy(grp => grp.Name));
```

Here is a demo based off of what I could gather from your PageFacilityDTO class:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kChCiu

And here is a screenshot of the returned results:

[image]

Comment: So, I don't see why this wouldn't work, except this error occurs when the View using the data is loaded: `RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'`

Comment: @travisdmcdaniel what happens if you try this instead:

`var groupedByState = _pageFacilityData.OrderBy(x => x.State).GroupBy(x => x.State).Select(g => g.Select(x => new FacilityDTO { State = g.Key, ClientID = x.ClientID, FacilityID = x.FacilityID, Name = x.Name})).ToList();`